# In excel how do I get the data before the second occurrence of a space?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example: Kerry Richardson Manager. I want to remove the word manager and have just Kerry Richardson or everything before the second space. The data starts in cell B2 down and I want the names without the titles from A2 down. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3881-excel-extract-text-before-second-space.html

Answer (score 0):

Use following formula

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,1)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works and also makes sure that there is no trailing space at the end:

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2,FIND(" ",B2,1)+1)-1)
```

[image]

The data is in column B as you said and the formula shown in C2 is used in A2 down...

Comment: Thanks for answering, it works, or it does when I try other data, but my data is doing something funny. I have to put the cursor before the M in Manager, hit backspace and then add the space back then hit enter and then the formula works, So I will have to do that manually which is still faster I guess, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the "spaces" in your data are spaces? As you see, I tested it to make sure it worked before posting.